# How to change popup color?

Tags: semantic-ui

I want to change the color of the popup to `inverted`, I use this:

```
$('path').popup({
        on:"click",
        transition:'vertical flip',
        duration: 300,
    });
```

But I dident fount in the docs how to add the key to add `inverted`, because if I add it directly to the dom, it works, so how to do it inside the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer from their [github page](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1928)

It is by adding `variation: 'inverted'`, here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/vx59te34/